# miniframes problems with header

Tags: beamer, minipage

I am having issues with my minipages header -- the left most part that says "introduction" never changes. I would be happy even totally getting rid of, which I can't seem to do.

[image: see here]

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%  This Beamer template was created by Cameron Bracken.
%%  Anyone can freely use or modify it for any purpose
%%  without attribution.
%%
%%  Last Modified: January 9, 2009
%%

\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

%% General document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}

\setbeamerfont{title like}{shape=\scshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\scshape}

\setbeamercolor*{lower separation line head}{bg=DeepSkyBlue4} 
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white} 
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=black} 
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=black} 

\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=black,bg=black!10} 

\renewcommand{\(}{\begin{columns}}
\renewcommand{\)}{\end{columns}}
\newcommand{\<}[1]{\begin{column}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\>}{\end{column}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}
    \color{gray}\vskip2pt~ \insertsection\hfill\insertpagenumber{} %
    of \insertpresentationendpage{} ~\vskip2pt
\end{beamercolorbox}
}


\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{\scshape Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\title{Retail Pricing and Consumer Behavior during a Tax Holiday}
%\subtitle{SUBTITLE}
\author{
    Cody Cook\\
}
\date{

    \today
}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\tableofcontents

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{\scshape Related Literature}
\subsection{frame 1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item A
\item Item B
\begin{itemize}
\item Subitem 1
\item Subtem 2
\end{itemize}
\item Item C
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{frame 2}
\begin{frame}{frame 2}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{frame 3}
\begin{frame}{frame 3}

\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{\scshape Data}
\subsection{frame 1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1}

\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\subsection{frame 1}
\begin{frame}{frame 1}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{\scshape Methodology}
\subsection{Frame 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}

\end{frame}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{\scshape Conclusion}
\subsection{Frame 1}
\begin{frame}{Frame 1}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comes due to `\section{\scshape Introduction}`. If you want to get rid of it totally, just delete that line or even better use `\section[]{\scshape Introduction}`. Note the empty `[]`, the optional argument.

[image]

Comment: @Craig You are welcome and thank you too. :)